# Blazor Parameter reference with at symbol but within a text

Tags: razor, blazor

How to make @Text act as Parameter but within a text?
For example, here

```
<div class="alert alert-@AlertClassType">some@Text</div>
```

some@Text is treated as a plain text,
but when *string Text="thing"* I'd expect 'something' in the result. I am clear, am I?

If I'd do

```
<div class="alert alert-@AlertClassType">some @Text</div>
```

it will "work" but that extra space before @ will also appear in the rendered content,
 how to avoid that?

Comment: Nope, letters and digits are problematic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@` symbol denotes the start of C# code block, if used with existing markup then you will need to specify that the `@` you're using is a code block explicitly by using `()`.

```
<div class="alert">some@(Text)</div>
```

Another tip,
If you want to specify that the `@()` you're using is **not** a code block then you can use the `@@` escape sequence.

```
<div class="alert">some@@(Text)</div>
```

[Snippet](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/mdOjlDlx40uJg9nv46)